# mService.getPurchase always returning 0 owned items, even after in app subscription purchase

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

```
try{
Bundle ownedItems = mService.getPurchases(3, getPackageName(),
                "inapp", null);
        if (ownedItems != null) {
            int response = ownedItems.getInt("RESPONSE_CODE");
            if (response == 0) {
                ArrayList ownedSkus = ownedItems
                        .getStringArrayList("INAPP_PURCHASE_ITEM_LIST");
                ArrayList purchaseDataList = ownedItems
                        .getStringArrayList("INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA_LIST");
                ArrayList signatureList = ownedItems
                        .getStringArrayList("INAPP_DATA_SIGNATURE");
                String continuationToken = ownedItems
                        .getString("INAPP_CONTINUATION_TOKEN");

                for (int i = 0; i < purchaseDataList.size(); ++i) {
                    String signature = null;
                    String purchaseData = (String) purchaseDataList.get(i);
                    if (signatureList != null)
                        signature = (String) signatureList.get(i);
                    String sku = (String) ownedSkus.get(i);
                    Log.d(TAG, "::isPremium:" + "sku:" + sku);
                    Log.d(TAG, "::isPremium:" + "purchaseData:"
                            + purchaseData);
                    Log.d(TAG, "::isPremium:" + "signature:" + signature);
                    if (sku.equalsIgnoreCase(SKU_PREMIUM)) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "::isPremium:" + "Already Purchased");
                        return true;
                    }

                    // do something with this purchase information
                    // e.g. display the updated list of products owned by
                    // user
                }

                // if continuationToken != null, call getPurchases again
                // and pass in the token to retrieve more items
            }
        }
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Will the above piece of code work only in Alpha release or Would I be able to debug it by running app through studio.

**Because, the user has purchased an in app subscription, but still I get only 0 items for "INAPP_PURCHASE_ITEM_LIST" during debug.**

Please someone help me on this.

Comment: Yes, I face this too..!!

Answer (score 0):

For subscription case looks like you need to change requested item type from `inapp` to `subs`:

```
Bundle ownedItems = mService.getPurchases(3, getPackageName(), "subs", null);
```

In this case you'll see only subscriptions in response.